# Tic-tac-toe with only crosses as quick as possible

Tags: sequence, grid, combinatorics, fastest-code, tic-tac-toe

As per [Luke's request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68678/tic-tac-toe-with-only-crosses#comment168138_68678) and [Peter Taylor's addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69097/34388) to this challenge.

#### Introduction

Everyone knows the game tic-tac-toe, but in this challenge, we are going to introduce a little twist. We are only going to use **crosses**. The first person who places three crosses in a row loses. An interesting fact is that the maximum amount of crosses before someone loses, is equal to **6**:

```
X X -
X - X
- X X
```

That means that for a 3 x 3 board, the maximum amount is **6**. So for N = 3, we need to output 6.

Another example, for N = 4, or a 4 x 4 board:

```
X X - X
X X - X
- - - -
X X - X
```

This is an optimal solution, you can see that the maximum amount of crosses is equal to **9**. An optimal solution for a 12 x 12 board is:

```
X - X - X - X X - X X -
X X - X X - - - X X - X
- X - X - X X - - - X X
X - - - X X - X X - X -
- X X - - - X - - - - X
X X - X X - X - X X - -
- - X X - X - X X - X X
X - - - - X - - - X X -
- X - X X - X X - - - X
X X - - - X X - X - X -
X - X X - - - X X - X X
- X X - X X - X - X - X
```

This results in **74**.

#### The task

Your task is to compute the results as fast as possible. I will run your code on the test case `13`. This will be done 5 times and then the average is taken of the run times. That is your final score. The lower, the better.

#### Test cases

```
N     Output
1       1
2       4
3       6
4       9
5       16
6       20
7       26
8       36
9       42
10      52
11      64
12      74
13      86
14      100
15      114
```

More information can be found at https://oeis.org/A181018.

#### Rules

- This is [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so the fastest submission wins!
- You must provide a *full program*.
- Please also provide how I have to run the program. I am not familiar with all programming languages and how they work, so I need a little bit of help here.
- Of course, your code needs to compute the *correct* result for each test case.

#### Submissions:

- **feersum** (C++11): 28s
- **Peter Taylor** (Java): 14m 31s

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76373/34388) and [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68678/34388).

Comment: Isn't this just a dupe of [the second question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68678/tic-tac-toe-with-only-crosses) as as far as I can tell, you've just changed the winning condition?

Comment: @muddyfish Altough the challenge itself look the same, I can ensure you that the approach for this challenge is _very_ different from my other challenge.

Comment: @muddyfish [Relevant meta discussion.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1876/8478) "Just changing the winning condition" can be a substantial change for a challenge. While it doesn't make sense to post a [tag:code-golf], [tag:fastest-algorithm] and [tag:fastest-code] for every possible challenge, there are some cases, where exploring a problem from two angles can add a lot of value to the site. I think this is such a case.

Comment: [Related Math.SE post by our Nathan Merrill.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1548710/50421)

Comment: Can you give the specs of the testing machine? Also, do you plan to allow multithreading? (I would usually prefer not as it just adds tedium).

Comment: @feersum The testing machine has a I7 core processor and 8GB ram. I have Windows 8 as OS. Multithreading is not allowed.

Comment: Wonderful challenge! (+1)

Comment: @Lembik Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## C++11, 28s

This also uses a dynamic programming approach based on rows. It took 28 seconds to run with argument 13 for me. My favorite trick is the `next` function which uses some bit bashing for finding the lexicographically next row arrangement satisfying a mask and the no-3-in-a-row rule.

#### Instructions

1. Install the latest [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) with SEH and Posix threads
2. Compile the program with `g++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 <filename>.cpp -o <executable name>`
3. Run with `<executable name> <n>`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#define popcount32 _mm_popcnt_u32
#else
#define popcount32 __builtin_popcount
#endif


using std::vector;

using row = uint32_t;
using xcount = uint8_t;

uint16_t rev16(uint16_t x) { // slow
    static const uint8_t revbyte[] {0,128,64,192,32,160,96,224,16,144,80,208,48,176,112,240,8,136,72,200,40,168,104,232,24,152,88,216,56,184,120,248,4,132,68,196,36,164,100,228,20,148,84,212,52,180,116,244,12,140,76,204,44,172,108,236,28,156,92,220,60,188,124,252,2,130,66,194,34,162,98,226,18,146,82,210,50,178,114,242,10,138,74,202,42,170,106,234,26,154,90,218,58,186,122,250,6,134,70,198,38,166,102,230,22,150,86,214,54,182,118,246,14,142,78,206,46,174,110,238,30,158,94,222,62,190,126,254,1,129,65,193,33,161,97,225,17,145,81,209,49,177,113,241,9,137,73,201,41,169,105,233,25,153,89,217,57,185,121,249,5,133,69,197,37,165,101,229,21,149,85,213,53,181,117,245,13,141,77,205,45,173,109,237,29,157,93,221,61,189,125,253,3,131,67,195,35,163,99,227,19,147,83,211,51,179,115,243,11,139,75,203,43,171,107,235,27,155,91,219,59,187,123,251,7,135,71,199,39,167,103,231,23,151,87,215,55,183,119,247,15,143,79,207,47,175,111,239,31,159,95,223,63,191,127,255};
    return uint16_t(revbyte[x >> 8]) | uint16_t(revbyte[x & 0xFF]) << 8;
}

// returns the next number after r that does not overlap the mask or have three 1's in a row
row next(row r, uint32_t m) {
    m |= r >> 1 & r >> 2;
    uint32_t x = (r | m) + 1;
    uint32_t carry = x & -x;
    return (r | carry) & -carry;
}

template<typename T, typename U> void maxequals(T& m, U v) {
    if (v > m)
        m = v;
}

struct tictac {
    const int n;
    vector<row> rows;
    size_t nonpal, nrows_c;
    vector<int> irow;
    vector<row> revrows;

    tictac(int n) : n(n) { }

    row reverse(row r) {
        return rev16(r) >> (16 - n);
    }

    vector<int> sols_1row() {
        vector<int> v(1 << n);
        for (uint32_t m = 0; !(m >> n); m++) {
            auto m2 = m;
            int n0 = 0;
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = n; i--; m2 >>= 1) {
                if (m2 & 1) {
                    n0 = 0;
                } else {
                    if (++n0 % 3)
                        score++;
                }
            }
            v[m] = score;
        }
        return v;
    }

    void gen_rows() {
        vector<row> pals;
        for (row r = 0; !(r >> n); r = next(r, 0)) {
            row rrev = reverse(r);
            if (r < rrev) {
                rows.push_back(r);
            } else if (r == rrev) {
                pals.push_back(r);
            }
        }
        nonpal = rows.size();
        for (row r : pals) {
            rows.push_back(r);
        }
        nrows_c = rows.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < nonpal; i++) {
            rows.push_back(reverse(rows[i]));
        }
        irow.resize(1 << n);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            irow[rows[i]] = i;
        }
        revrows.resize(1 << n);
        for (row r = 0; !(r >> n); r++) {
            revrows[r] = reverse(r);
        }
    }

    // find banned locations for 1's given 2 above rows
    uint32_t mask(row a, row b) {
        return ((a & b) | (a >> 1 & b) >> 1 | (a << 1 & b) << 1) /*& ((1 << n) - 1)*/;
    }

    int calc() {
        if (n < 3) {
            return n * n;
        }
        gen_rows();
        int tdim = n < 5 ? n : (n + 3) / 2;
        size_t nrows = rows.size();
        xcount* t = new xcount[2 * nrows * nrows_c]{};
#define tb(nr, i, j) t[nrows * (nrows_c * ((nr) & 1) + (i)) + (j)]

        // find optimal solutions given 2 rows for n x k grids where 3 <= k <= ceil(n/2) + 1

        {
            auto s1 = sols_1row();
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows_c; i++) {
                row a = rows[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < nrows; j++) {
                    row b = rows[j];
                    uint32_t m = mask(b, a) & ~(1 << n);
                    tb(3, i, j) = s1[m] + popcount32(a << 16 | b);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int r = 4; r <= tdim; r++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows_c; i++) {
                row a = rows[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < nrows; j++) {
                    row b = rows[j];
                    bool rev = j >= nrows_c;
                    auto cj = rev ? j - nrows_c : j;
                    uint32_t m = mask(a, b);
                    for (row c = 0; !(c >> n); c = next(c, m)) {
                        row cc = rev ? revrows[c] : c;
                        int count = tb(r - 1, i, j) + popcount32(c);
                        maxequals(tb(r, cj, irow[cc]), count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int ans = 0;
        if (tdim == n) { // small sizes
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows_c; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrows; j++) {
                    maxequals(ans, tb(n, i, j));
                }
            }
        } else {
            int tdim2 = n + 2 - tdim;
            // get final answer by joining two halves' solutions down the middle
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows_c; i++) {
                int apc = popcount32(rows[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < nrows; j++) {
                    row b = rows[j];
                    int top = tb(tdim2, i, j);
                    int bottom = j < nrows_c ? tb(tdim, j, i) : tb(tdim, j - nrows_c, i < nonpal ? i + nrows_c : i);
                    maxequals(ans, top + bottom - apc - popcount32(b));
                }
            }
        }
        delete[] t;
        return ans;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n;
    if (argc < 2 || (n = std::stoi(argv[1])) < 0 || n > 16) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << tictac{ n }.calc() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Java, 14m 31s

This is essentially the program which I posted to OEIS after using it to extend the sequence, so it's a good reference for other people to beat. I've tweaked it to take the board size as the first command-line argument.

```java
public class A181018 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(calc(n));
    }

    private static int calc(int n) {
        if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("n");
        if (n < 3) return n * n;

        // Dynamic programming approach: given two rows, we can enumerate the possible third row.
        // sc[i + rows.length * j] is the greatest score achievable with a board ending in rows[i], rows[j].
        int[] rows = buildRows(n);
        byte[] sc = new byte[rows.length * rows.length];
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            int qsc = Integer.bitCount(rows[j]);
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) sc[k++] = (byte)(qsc + Integer.bitCount(rows[i]));
        }

        int max = 0;
        for (int h = 2; h < n; h++) {
            byte[] nsc = new byte[rows.length * rows.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                int p = rows[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                    int q = rows[j];
                    // The rows which follow p,q cannot intersect with a certain mask.
                    int mask = (p & q) | ((p << 2) & (q << 1)) | ((p >> 2) & (q >> 1));
                    for (int k = 0; k < rows.length; k++) {
                        int r = rows[k];
                        if ((r & mask) != 0) continue;

                        int pqrsc = (sc[i + rows.length * j] & 0xff) + Integer.bitCount(r);
                        int off = j + rows.length * k;
                        if (pqrsc > nsc[off]) nsc[off] = (byte)pqrsc;
                        if (pqrsc > max) max = pqrsc;
                    }
                }
            }

            sc = nsc;
        }

        return max;
    }

    private static int[] buildRows(int n) {
        // Array length is a tribonacci number.
        int c = 1;
        for (int a = 0, b = 1, i = 0; i < n; i++) c = a + (a = b) + (b = c);

        int[] rows = new int[c];
        int i = 0, j = 1, val;
        while ((val = rows[i]) < (1 << (n - 1))) {
            if (val > 0) rows[j++] = val * 2;
            if ((val & 3) != 3) rows[j++] = val * 2 + 1;
            i++;
        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

Save to `A181018.java`; compile as `javac A181018.java`; run as `java A181018 13`. On my computer it takes about 20 minutes to execute for this input. It would probably be worth parallelising it.

Comment: How long have you been running it? You're still adding terms to the OEIS, I see.

Comment: @mbomb007, I'm not still running it. As you can tell from the OEIS dates, it took several days to run for `n=16`; I extrapolated that it would take about a month for `n=17`, so I didn't try to run it for that. Memory usage was also becoming a major nuisance. (PS I'm currently using 2 of my 4 cores for a non-PPCG programming challenge: http://azspcs.com/Contest/Tetrahedra/Standings )

Answer (score 0):

## matlab, cplex, baseline?

This code is modified from the MATLAB code provided on [A181018](https://oeis.org/A181018)

### how to run?

1. download `cplex` and `yalmip` folder, then place them in matlab `toolbox` folder
2. matlab ui, HOME->Set Path->Add Folder With Subfolders, add the 2 folders and their subfolders to path
3. run `main.m`

```
% A181018.m
function v = A181018(n)
%
Grid = [1:n]' * ones(1, n) + n*ones(n, 1)*[0:n-1];
f = -ones(n^2, 1);
A = sparse(4*(n-2)*(n-1), n^2);
count = 0;
for i =1:n
    for j = 1:n-2
        count = count+1;
        A(count, [Grid(i, j), Grid(i, j+1), Grid(i, j+2)]) = 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:n-2
    for j = 1:n
        count = count+1;
        A(count, [Grid(i, j), Grid(i+1, j), Grid(i+2, j)]) = 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:n-2
    for j = 1:n-2
        count = count+2;
        A(count-1, [Grid(i, j+2), Grid(i+1, j+1), Grid(i+2, j)]) = 1;
        A(count, [Grid(i, j), Grid(i+1, j+1), Grid(i+2, j+2)]) = 1;
    end
end
b = 2*ones(4*(n-2)*(n-1), 1);


options = cplexoptimset;
options.MaxTime = 120;
options.Algorithm = 'auto';
% [x, v, exitflag, output] = cplexbilp(f, A, b,options);
[~, v, ~, ~] = cplexbilp(f, A, b,options);  % Solve binary integer programming problems.
v=-v;
end
```

```
% main.m
clear all;close all;clc;
tic
for n = 1:11
    A(n) = A181018(n);
end
A % Robert Israel, Jan 14 2016
toc
```

### Reference

See [*Getting Started with CPLEX for MATLAB*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohamed_Mourad_Lafifi/post/do_cplex_solver_in_GAMS_and_CPLEX_software_have_same_results/attachment/59d6479379197b80779a268d/AS%3A463101872087041%401487423498775/download/Getting+Started+with+CPLEX+for+MATLAB.pdf) for a quick start.

[cplexbilp - IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.8.0.0?topic=functions-cplexbilp)